# Agreement of adjectives with nouns

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, género, concordancia-gramatical

¿Es correcta esta frase?

> Coge la bolsa por el asa pequeño.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is incorrect. The adjective *pequeño* must agree with the noun *asa* which is feminine.

The tricky part is that, since the word *asa* starts with an stressed "a" (/a/ tónica in Spanish), it won't use the feminine article "la," but rather the masculine "el" to avoid "la asa," which would sound awkward. You can see this happen with other feminine words that start with stressed "a":

> El águila
>
> El agua
>
> El alma
>
> El aula

even words that start with an "h" followed by stressed "a":

> El hacha

Note that you would not be doing this if the "a" were not stressed

> La arena (stress is on the letter "e")
>
> La actitud (stress is on the letter "u")
>
> La agencia (stress is on the letter "e")

You will still use this "feminized" form of the article "el" for declinations of words that start with stressed "a," even if the declined word loses the stress on the "a" (/a/ átona in Spanish).

> El agüita (not *la agüita*)

You won't be using it either word composed feminine words in which the first word starts with an stressed "a" but the composed word has a non-stressed "a":

> La aguamarina (not *el aguamarina*. Stress in in letter "i")

The word *asa* has a stressed "a", so the correct form would be

> Coge la bolsa por el asa pequeñ**a**.

Comment: You may wish to add that's when the word begins with a stressed a. Otherwise, it's still la

Comment: @guifa, like in "la agencia". Thanks, I'll update that.

Comment: Note: The RAE recommends **against** using *el/un* with *agüita*, exactly because of the change in stress:   

"Con el diminutivo *agüita* deben usarse las formas *la* y *una*, pues el acento ya no recae en la /a/ inicial: *«La “agüita de panela” [...] no sustituye a la leche»* (Traversa Cine [Arg. 1984]); *«Te vas a tomar una agüita de ortiga con cinamón»* (Gamboa Páginas [Col. 1998])."   

http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=agua