# Should I use "buena" or "bueno" when referring to "una persona"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, género, concordancia-gramatical

I'm confused on whether I say:

> Pepe es una persona buena

or

> Pepe es una persona bueno.

(Pepe is a man, so I find the male/female agreement thing confusing when using persona)

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10385/12637

Comment: Also note that plurals and verbs also agree with the noun even if the concept is plural and the noun singular/ La gente **es** enojad**a**. The people are angry.

Comment: The most common way of saying this in Mexico at least would be "Pepe es [muy] buena gente."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of the sex of the person you are referring to, the adjective must always agree with the noun it modifies. So if "bueno" modifies "persona", and "persona"  is a feminine word, the adjective must be also feminine.

Note that it is a common mistake (even for Spanish speakers) to mistake the "gender" of the words with the "sex" of the people. You can use feminine words to refer to male people (and vice versa), as in "Juan es una persona". You use "persona" (feminine) for a male person (Juan).